# We don't need the security tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The tag [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) exists on the site. It should be an [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60425/start-se-sites-with-a-tag-blacklist/62183#62183) (blacklisted, but treated as a site tag when evaluating incoming migrations).

Please add to this the [information-security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-security) tag too... Not sure what other variations we will find, but that's it for now.

<sub>This is a developer-only action.</sub>

Comment: Agreed. It's kinda redundant.

Comment: @Shog9 please see the additional tag to be removed...

Comment: @AviD I think that should be a separate thing. “Intrinsic tag” is specifically a tag that describes the whole scope of the site. [tag:information-security] is unlikely to come back in a migration (it only has a handful of occurrences on SO), we can simply remove it manually. Also [tag:security-effectiveness], which isn't used meaningfully.

Comment: @Gilles I think information-security is also a null tag, nearly completely equivalent with the scope of the site, by definition. (Yes there are some areas which are tangential to infosec, or only partially venn-overlapped, but this is the default. )

Comment: @AviD Anyway, [tag:information-security], what [tag:information-security]?

Comment: @Gilles niiiicely done. Still wouldnt want it coming back, though... If a newbie really wants a [security] tag, let them use [tag:security-theater] like everybody else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh hey, this was completed some time ago. The [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag has been blacklisted.

Comment: AviD removed [meta-tag:status-completed] because he wanted [tag:information-security] blacklisted (it might have come in with a migration, I don't remember).

Comment: @Gilles Eh, there are no posts in "information-security" right now. Looks like it hasn't come back? Let me know if it does and we can see about blacklisting it as well.

Comment: I've checked, we had 5 questions tagged [tag:information-security] probably starting with [this one](http://security.stackexchange.com/posts/36254/revisions) and now the tag only survives on SO (for the next few minutes anyway). Not worth adding it to the blacklist then.