# Please Blacklist the Secure tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Similarly to the [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag mentioned [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1291/485), The tag [secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secure) exists on the site. It should be an [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60425/start-se-sites-with-a-tag-blacklist/62183#62183) (blacklisted, but treated as a site tag when evaluating incoming migrations).

<sub>This is a developer-only action.</sub>

Comment: Oh lawd, let's get rid of this atrocity.

Comment: I have already removed it from all posts - just need it added to the blacklist :-) Not sure why we didn't include it with those others previously.